# Screeching Feedback sound in Node.js

Tags: socket.io, video-streaming, webrtc, getusermedia, video-conferencing

I implementing webRTC with socket.io with for signaling, but earlier as soon as I opened the URL it used to give screeching sound, but then after some research, I added a muted attribute in the local video tag so it got fixed but now when I call someone then both the browser have a high pitched screeching sound(less on macOS chrome and more on android chrome), the code which I using as a basis is from [this](https://github.com/michaelneu/howto-webrtc/blob/master/public/web.js) tutorial, I modified the code on line [148](https://github.com/michaelneu/howto-webrtc/blob/ca55e9defb89eca28c36bef081fa85653af7e3cc/public/web.js#L148) to have `audio: true` and the HTML video tag for the local video to have muted, rest of the code is exactly same as the [repo](https://github.com/michaelneu/howto-webrtc).

I have read a lot of articles on it but I am not able to find a solution to the screeching. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Your microphone makes that sound

Comment: any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Get a new microphone

Comment: That most likely. Could also be driver errors, but small chance for that from my perspective

Comment: it happens in the application that I wrote and the question is about that, it works well on skype and other such apps

Comment: skype has noise cancelling. So it would remove any noise anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both the devices are near to each other, then it causes this sound. If you move the devices far away, then there won't be screeching sound...

This happens with other video chat applications like zoom and google-meet also...

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Thanks, I was keeping the devices very near to each other while testing but when I took them far from each other it started to work.